# Create a loop for a csv output file R

Tags: r, loops, csv

I'm trying to create a loop in my script in order to obtain an output file. In my script I already have other 2 loops for reading input files. At the end of my script I have a df in my environment that I'd like to save as a .csv with the name of the input files. Here a simplified version of my codes:

```
    filePdbs <- Sys.glob("*.pdb")
    fileTurns <- Sys.glob("*.txt")
    for (filePdb in filePdbs) {
      "pdb" <- print(read.pdb(filePdb))
       
    ##other stuff here 
      
      "coord" <- print(read.pdb(filePdb)) 

    ##other stuff here 

      for (fileTurn in fileTurns) {
      "turn" <- read.delim(fileTurn, header = T, sep = "")

  ## here I have lines for merging info from pdb and txt and I obtain my df that I'd like to save as csv
    
      }
    }
```

For this 2 input file loops I have to create the third global one for the csv output having the same name of input file.
Input files are something like "1abc_A.pdb" and "1abc_A.txt", I'd like to have as output "1abc_A.csv"
How can I do it?

Comment: First you need to correct the basic error of not indexing the assignments inside those loops. You are overwriting the results of your input efforts.

Comment: Also, why are your returned objects quoted, e.g. "turn" <- . . . "? Also you are reading looping through the `fileTurns` each time you read one  `filePdb`. That seems like a waste of time. If the files are not gigantic, it would be more efficient to read all of each type into a list and then use a loop to process the list.

Comment: I need to do my script on 1072 files pdb and 1072 files txt that I have in the same folder

Comment: Also, I merge information that I have in both pdb and txt, so I need to read them at the same time. But  I'm new with R so if there's a better way to do it pls let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several issues with your code, as already pointed out in the comments, but the actual question is how to change the file ending in the string, as far as I understand the question.

The easiest way would be to use `sub(pattern="pdb$", replacement="csv", x=filePdb)`. This finds the letters 'pdb' at the end of strings ($ means end of line) and replaces it with 'csv'. I would put this line in your second look immediately after modifying your variables. Alternatively you could use `filePdbs` instead of `filePdb` and save all modified file names first before using them.

So here is what I would change in your code example:

When you read-in the files you don't need `print` which in most cases prints the content to the consol, but we want to save the file content in a variable.

Variables do not get quotes. Putting quotes around the name changes the meaning and you get a character string in which you cannot store anything.

You seems to read the filePdb file twice within the loop. This is inefficient. If you want to access the matrix with the coordinates to store it in a variable called 'coord', you can get the matrix with `pdb$xyz` (we do talk here about the bio3d package, right?).

So then you loop through every .txt file for each .pdb file. ([no of txt] * [no of pdb]). I think you might have file pairs and if so you need to open only 1 txt file per pdb file. You could achieve this with

```
for (i in seq(along=filePdbs)) {
    pdb <- read.pdb(filePdbs[i])
    turn <- read.delim(fileTurn[i], header = T, sep = "")
    # ...
}
```

(Be sure the `sep` argument fits your purpose.)

Finally, as mentioned above, put the `write.csv()` (or for more control of output settings `write.table()`) inside your inner loop and modify the name with `sub()`.

```
filePdbs <- Sys.glob("*.pdb")
fileTurns <- Sys.glob("*.txt")

for (filePdb in filePdbs) {
    pdb <- read.pdb(filePdb)
       
    ##other stuff here 
      
    coord <- pdb$xyz

    ##other stuff here 

    for (fileTurn in fileTurns) {
        turn <- read.delim(fileTurn, header = T, sep = "")

        ## here I have lines for merging info from pdb and txt and I obtain my df that I'd like to save as csv
    
        write.csv(result,
                  file=sub("pdb$", "csv", x=filePdb),
                  row.names=F)
    
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot!!!  and yes, it's bio3d package. I'm gonna modify my error but about coordinates it's a bit different because I don't need coordinates af all atoms but just the ones I selected so I need to read all the pdb files, then to select only what I'm interested in and at the end to get coordinates. Anyway I tried your solution and it works! thank you!

Comment: I was checking output files and I got all csv files but opening them they're all the same file with different name. Contents of files are the same, the last that R read

Comment: I have a list of file with different names but the same content

Comment: and also, running the script on 8 files (always having the error about contents) it goes without problem, instead running the script on 1072 files it crashes. It seems like R is not having enought time to do it simultaneously  and so it crashes. Maybe it's necessary to create a third global loop that, after doing loops about pdb and txt, writes the csv. So opening it at the start and closing it at the end of the whole script. In this way maybe it is also possible to avoid the error about contents

Comment: Nice to hear that you made progress. So the file name problem is solved and now we have a second issue about the content. Unfortunately it is not very clear to me how you want to manipulate the data and therefore I afraid I cannot give you very effective advice w/o more details.

Opening all files sounds indeed a it challenging for your R session and generally you should try open as few files as possible (but at the same time opening files with the lowest frequency  - most likely once). The best strategy depends of course on your task.

Comment: Then you say that you save the files under a new name and the content is not altered. Without knowing how you process the data I cannot really say what is going wrong. Two general reasons could be that you either don't change the content of the pdb variable or the write command is in a wrong place. Of course there are other thinks possible.

Comment: Maybe at this point you need to give a toy example. This command could give some dummy files:`filePdbs <- rep(system.file("examples/1hel.pdb", package="bio3d"), 5)`. It is from the help page and finds an example file from the bio3d package in your system, wrapped in an repeat command multiplying the file path 5 times. 'fileTurns' is probably a table judging from the import function you use. Can you made a dummy data.frame for instance? What are the relevant columns? What do you need to combine/replace exactly, both in respect to the objects content as well as from which files?

Comment: CanThisWork as dummy data?
turnList <- list(fileContent1 = data.frame(id=1:10, someText=sample(letters,size=10,replace=TRUE), diffText=LETTERS[1:10]),
fileContent2 = data.frame(id=1:10, someText=sample(letters,size=10,replace=TRUE), diffText=LETTERS[16:25]),
fileContent3 = data.frame(id=1:10, someText=sample(letters,size=10,replace=TRUE), diffText=LETTERS[12:21]),
fileContent4 = data.frame(id=1:10, someText=sample(letters,size=10,replace=TRUE), diffText=LETTERS[2:11]),
fileContent5 = data.frame(id=1:10, someText=sample(letters,size=10,replace=TRUE), diffText=LETTERS[6:15]))
str(turnList)

Comment: And then finally, how did you approach the data modification?

Comment: you sound to me practical with bio3d, so if i'm gonna explain you what I'm doing you will understand. At first, I'm reading a pdb files and getting only some atoms (so I subset the data). From the pdb file I have 2 df: 1) with information about aminoacids and atoms called "pdb" 2) about coordinates of atoms I'm interested in called "coord". After, I calculate distances between 2 atoms from coord getting a new df called "dist" where are reported distances between atoms. The next step is to merge info of "dist" and "pdb", so I add a column with distances in my "pdb" dataframe.

Comment: for doing this I'm using the first loop calling the pdb file.

Comment: The second part of my script is to import a txt file as df and to subset it. this df called "turn" where I'd like to add information from the df "pdb" created before. So after doing this, I have to write a csv as output that contains info from the txt and info from df "pdb". For getting the txt I'm using the second loop that calls one txt file for each iteration.